# get refresh token from authorization code google oauth2

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to get Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens.

here is my post call data I am sending to google.

```
var requestBody = {
            code:**mycode**,
            grant_type:'authorization_code',
            client_secret: **mysecret**,
            client_id: **clientId**,
            redirect_uri:"http://localhost:3000"
        }
```

I am sending this data via POST call to "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

using meteor post call

```
Meteor.http.call('POST', requestUrl, {'data': requestBody});
```

but i am getting this error from google.

```
Error: failed [400] {  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: " }
```

any idea why i am getting this error.

ideally it should return with

```
{
 "access_token":"sometoken",
 "expires_in":3920,
 "token_type":"Bearer",
 "refresh_token":"refresh token"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue, instead of sending the data as `data.send` it as params.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when sending the post that the body is in HTTP URL query parameters not posting as JSon.

> code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code

Also the content type of the post should be  `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` again not JSON